# Coverage of duration per hour calculation

Tags: python, datetime

Given a start time `Timestamp('2015-05-06 09:40:45')` and an end time `Timestamp('2015-05-06 011:12:13')`, I want to determine the number of minutes covered per hour of this duration.

That is, I want the following output:

- hour 9 -- 19.25 minutes
- hour 10 -- 60.00 minutes
- hour 11 -- 12.22 minutes

I have an algorithm in mind, but I'm stumped comparing `int` and `timestamp`.

Comment: `Timestamp` isn't a part of Python standard library, is it?

Comment: I used the `datetime` package to generate the durations, but after placing them on a pandas data frame, the resulting column dtype is now `pandas.tslib.Timestamp `.

Answer (score 0):

We are assuming that the start date and end date are the same.

```
from datetime import datetime
starttime = datetime(year = 2015, month = 5, day =6, hour=9, minute=40, second=45)
endtime = datetime(year = 2015, month = 5, day =6, hour=11, minute=12, second=13)

for i in range(starttime.hour, endtime.hour+1):
    if i == starttime.hour:
        rightbound = datetime(starttime.year, starttime.month, starttime.day, hour=(i+1), minute=0, second=0)
        print starttime.hour, (rightbound - starttime).seconds/60.
    elif i == endtime.hour:
        leftbound = datetime(starttime.year, starttime.month, starttime.day, hour=(i), minute=0, second=0)
        print leftbound.hour, (endtime - leftbound).seconds/60.
    else:
        print i, "60"
```

The (nth hour, # of minutes) output is:

```
9 19.25
10 60
11 12.2166666667
```